# How can you aggregate different coordinates for a camera trap site so that each site has the same position?

Tags: r, coordinates, aggregate, conditional-statements

I have camera trap data of camera trap sites recorded in excel for 10 years of consecutive field trips. At each camera trap site, someone has written the coordinates slightly different on some occasions. This has made many different coordinates for the same camera trap site although they were in the same place. How do I manage this data so all coordinates are the same for each site using the aggregate function in R?

I have tried to do this manually in excel but it is just too much work as there are thousands of entries.

I have not tried to do it in R yet as I don't understand the Aggregate function.

I expect that each site would have the same coordinates so when it is plotted on a map, it would be a lot tidier.

Comment: If you want to normalize such data automatically, you have to write some code for that. Without you providing some sample data, there is no way to help you more detailled

Answer (score 0):

Using very simple data:

```
siteId <- c(1,1,2,2)
lats <- c(123, 124, 567, 568)
lons <- c(321, 320, 765, 876)
df <- data.frame(siteId, lats, lons)

df1 <-aggregate(df,by=list(siteId), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
df2 <-aggregate(df,by=list(siteId), FUN=min, na.rm=TRUE)
df3 <-aggregate(df,by=list(siteId), FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

the first output (df1) would give you a set of coordinates that is calculated as the mean of all the coordinate variations for each site. 
The second output (df2) would give you a set of coordinates that is calculated as the min of all the variations for each site.
The second output (df2) would give you a set of coordinates that is calculated as the max of all the variations for each site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I was busy with something else recently but I will give this a go and let you know. Thanks again.